# Routing issue on controller with irregular pluralization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Application has `BusinessSessionsController` to handle logins and logged in sessions for `Businesses` Controller and `Business` model. When logging in successfully the user should be routed to `.../businesses/4` where '4' is the id of the respective business. Instead rails builds the following URL `.../business.4`

My guess is that this may have to do with the irregular pluralization of the word 'business'. When I run the same code for a `users` controller, `user` model, i.e. regular pluralization, it works just fine.

I tried setting an irregular inflector as shown below, but adding it made no difference. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes section 4.8

```
config/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'business', 'businesses'
end
```

Current controller:

```
class BusinessSessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  business = Business.find_by(email: params[:business_session][:email].downcase)
  if business && business.authenticate(params[:business_session][:password])
    business_log_in business
    redirect_to business
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    redirect_to business_url
  end  
end

end
```

Routes

```
get 'business' => 'businesses#new' #this page has the login form
get 'business_login' => 'business_sessions#new'
post 'business_login' =>  'business_sessions#create'
resources :businesses
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the irregular inflection, rails handles this correctly. I created a routes.rb with just `resources :business`, running `rake routes` yields:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
   businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)          businesses#index
              POST   /businesses(.:format)          businesses#create
 new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)      businesses#new
edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format) businesses#edit
     business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#show
              PATCH  /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
              PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
              DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#destroy
```

However you previous definition

```
get 'business' => 'businesses#new' #this page has the login form
```

causes the trouble, since this will generate a helper that is also called `business_url`:

```
  Prefix Verb URI Pattern         Controller#Action
business GET  /business(.:format) businesses#new
```

The difference is that one helper has an ID and the other one doesn't, due to rails' convention that the priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority - the one without the ID wins.

If you call `redirect to: business`, what happens is that the `business_url` helper without the ID is called and the ID of the business is treated as "format".

**TL;DR Two ways to resolve this:**

1) The railsy way, is to remove your `get 'business' => 'businesses#new'` route and use the `new_business_url` helper instead. The url will then look like `/businesses/new`

2) You really want the URL to be `/business`, then you can do some trickery:

```
  get 'business' => 'businesses#new', as: :new_business #this page has the login form
  resources :businesses, except: [:new]
```

This will yield the following routes:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
 new_business GET    /business(.:format)            businesses#new
   businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)          businesses#index
              POST   /businesses(.:format)          businesses#create
edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format) businesses#edit
     business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#show
              PATCH  /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
              PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#update
              DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)      businesses#destroy
```

You still have to replace your call to `business_url` with `new_business_url` but the URL will now look like `/business`.